# Hide duplicates, group similar items list sencha touch 2

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm making a phonegap + sencha app which displays a list (from an xml file I do no not control).
Right now I'm facing two problems.

- Duplicate entries - Some entries share all fields. e.g. {Group}, {Analysis}, {Age}, {Ref} - How do I automatically hide all but one of these entries?
- Similar entries - Some entries share some fields. e.g. {Group}, {Analysis} but differ on others e.g. {Age}, {Ref}. Right now I'm using a detailview to display another field (as per senchalearn.github.com/Presidents/). Is it possible to make it so that for entries sharing two specified fields all will be hidden and only one entry will be shown in the list (only displaying the two common fields) which has a detailview displaying all the entries?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you need to pre-calculate the xml list to ensure there are no duplicates.
But it should'nt take more than a few lines to do so.
Simply throw them all in a store, sort them and run through all items to kill duplicates.
(Something like: If previous record = current record remove current record from store)

Similar entries.
You could run through the store and write all data to a json string, which you need.
As a data source you give the json string.